# Как сделать текст поверх картинки.

Tags: html, javascript

Есть сайт http://proxy4you.noip.me/ и на нем есть скрипт отображения даты, но увы, я не знаю как можно сделать так, чтобы дата отображалась поверх изображения. Наверняка это можно сделать прямо в JS, но я его не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrdmt

Кривовато, но так можно.

Comment: Предложенный Вами вариант подходит, только там текст слева, а нужно, чтобы был справа.

Answer (score 3):

Можно с помощью `canvas`.

Набросал [работающий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/fpd5kej8/), где скрипт работает с первым попавшимся изображением на странице, замещая его элементом `<canvas>`, в который копируется содержание изображения и поверх пишется текст.

```
(function($){

    var image = $('img').first()
      , w = image.width()
      , h = image.height()
      , src = image.attr('src')
      , canvas = $('<canvas>')
        .attr({width:w, height:h})
        .css({width:w, height:h})
        .appendTo( 'body').get(0)
      , context = canvas.getContext('2d')
      , ImageObject = new Image()
      , D = new Date()
      , M = ("января,февраля,марта,апреля,мая,июня,июля,августа,сентября,октября,ноября,декабря").split(',')
      , text = D.getDate() + ' ' + M[ D.getMonth()] + ' ' + D.getFullYear()
    ;

    ImageObject.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage( ImageObject, 0, 0);
        context.font = "20px Arial";
        context.fillText( text, 10, h-10);
        image.remove();
    };

    ImageObject.src = src;

})( jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
var d = new Date();

var day=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday",
"Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var node = document.createElement("DIV");
var textnode = document.createTextNode(d.getDate());
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementsByClassName('style1')[0].appendChild(node);
```